# How to debug Java UNO in LibreOffice?

Tags: java, debugging, libreoffice

I have been researching on the topic for a couple of days and wrote a simple UNO component to work with the Spreadsheet. The main challenge I faced during the process is whenever the LO cannot find a class (i.e. some required jar is not included in the oxt package), the thread dies absolutely silently without throwing any exception. The only way to find out is to step trace all the suspecious code which is both frustrating and very time consuming. Only then can I see the exception message text and exception itself being created. Unfortunately, this exception is never really thrown in the environment I have or is silenced in some way.

Is there any way to enable LO to throw exceptions/see stack trace for debug purposes? Is there any location where LP puts java console output?
Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What is an "UNO component"?

Comment: Universal Network Object in terms of OpenOffice/LibreOffice - part of an extension which allows to add custom functionality and UI to the standart Office functionality, like add a menu to call your own UI developed in different languages like C++, Python or Java in my case.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Im using Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0):

If you have not done so yet, I recommend getting the [BookmarkInsertion example](https://api.libreoffice.org/examples/java/Text/) to work.  Be sure that the application can find the main 4 jars in the classpath: juh.jar, jurt,jar, ridl,jar, unoil.jar.

Are you running the component from the Java IDE, for example, NetBeans? 
 Normally, build errors and exceptions are reported in the appropriate output window at the bottom of the IDE, and this is where java console output appears as well.

Otherwise, if you have already installed the OXT file in LibreOffice and are running it without a Java IDE, then there is no console output displayed.  In that case, you may want to log to a file with something like log4j.  However, error messages may still be able to pop up in a message box, depending on the error.

**EDIT**:

For an example in Eclipse, I followed the instructions at https://github.com/LibreOffice/loeclipse.  To show messages:

- *Window -> Show View -> Console*
- *Window -> Show View -> Error Log*

When I renamed jurt.jar to jurt0.jar so that it cannot be found, then the following was shown in the Console pane.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.sun.star.comp.loader.JavaLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

`System.err.println` also writes to the Console pane.  I modified `ActionOneDialog.java` as follows.

```
public void show() {
    System.err.println("show() BEGIN");
    dialog.execute();
    System.err.println("show() END");
}
```

Comment: Im using Eclipse so I started off with the [starter extension](https://github.com/smehrbrodt/libreoffice-starter-extension) which I customized to test features I need in the real world application (http access to the outside world + GUI).
Ive been running/debugging it from the IDE. The trouble, which I mentioned, is it does not show any error if ClassNotFoundException arises:

`try { class initialization code that fails } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}`

shows nothing, whereas when I step trace it in IDE, I see the point where the code breaks and the exception is being created

Comment: both console and error log are on in IDE. Renamed my httpcore-4.4.9.jar to httpcore-4.4.9_1.jar as you suggested to cause ClassNotFoundException. When I click the button in my GUI and the code flow tries to create the object that it cannot, neither console nor error log pane are showing anything. Just nothing is happening in GUI as though I havent clicked at all. Maybe the reason is the error happens within the event trigger?

Comment: Try starting a new project with the LibreOffice Starter Extension as I did, and rename jurt.jar.  [Maven httpcore.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.1) is not related to LibreOffice, so you may need to ask a different question for help with that.